# Lua : delete table which contains graphic objects

Tags: lua, coronasdk

In my game I've a gamefield object (table) which contains all other graphic (display.newRect) and non graphic objects. Now I'm looking for good way to restart game, is there way to remove only gamefield object (table) and cause that inserted objects will be removed, graphic and non graphic together? Or I should remove graphic objects manually? 
Thank you.

Comment: it's a bit difficult to understand what you mean, can you show some code or pseudocode to illustrate what would like to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put all your graphical objects in a display group (display.newGroup). 
When you remove the display group, it will remove all the images, rects, etc.

You can add other attributes to the display group (i.e. use it as your gamefield object).

If you do it this way, you just need to remove the group (group:removeSelf()) and create a new one.

Comment: Thank you, I'll try it together with solution provided by @W.B.

Answer (score 2):

You need to create a method for the table (eg destroy()) that would traverse it and remove objects from the scene.

You would want to create a metatable for gamefield tables and call your method in __gc metamethod, if you're using Lua 5.2.1. If not, just call it explicitly.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your advice, but how do you know can I check which Lua version am I using in Lua Glider?

Comment: @Anatoly I was under the impression that you're using Corona, so it's more a matter of checking which version your Sdk ships with.

Comment: Sorry, I mislead you. I use Corona SDK together with LUA Glider IDE.

Answer (score -1):

You will need to remove them yourself.