# How to find which version of Lua do I use?

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I develop app by using Lua Glider 2 + Corona SDK latest release. How can I find which version of Lua do it use? Thank you.

Comment: Why do you need to know? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I'd like to use metamethod __gc for remove display objects from table and as I understand I can do it only in Lua 5.2

Comment: Use LuaJIT - it implements Lua version 5.1 with some additional features from 5.2 (such as `__gc` metamethod)

Comment: Why do you need this? Lua does auto gc, the __gc stuff is really only useful for objects that hold system resources like mutex, file handles, database connections etc, but Corona Lua is sandboxed and doesn't support any of that. Corona display objects are automatically freed, you just have to make sure you aren't keeping other references yourself in your module (if you do, __gc won't be called anyways -- not until all refs nilled). Maybe post a question explaining why you think you need this in your particular case then you can find better solution.

Comment: Thank you for your attention, I really appreciate it especially issue like this can save a lot of time to me. Actually I've post the question before and get this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/21509113/947111 but meanwhile I've implemented it in other way (the accepted answer).

Comment: I apologise for my English((

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the global variable [`_VERSION`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#pdf-_VERSION) to find out.

```
print( _G._VERSION )
```

Comment: Thank you, it works. Maybe you know how can to turn from 5.1 to 5.2 is it possible at all?

Comment: @Anatoly I wouldn't suggest upgrading to Lua 5.2 just yet. First confirm if all the libraries you are using for your app are stable in the newer version or not.

Comment: I do not think you can choose which version of Lua is used by Corona. Everything is sandboxed. Even C extensions are not allowed (except in enterprise version, AFAICT, very pricey http://coronalabs.com/pricing/).

Comment: You cannot change the version of Lua that Corona SDK uses.